# How to use observed object value in init?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'd like to load a URL that is string interpolated to fetch a static JSON. I have tried declaring the variables inside the init() but haven't had any luck. I am very new to Swift and SwiftUI, so there is a def a gap in knowledge.

```
class FetchVersion: ObservableObject {
    @Published var version = String() {
        didSet {
            print("\(self.version) created in VersionView")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/realms/na.json") else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClientVersion.self, from: todoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.version = decodedData.patch
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

So the purpose of that class is to decode the JSON mentioned and return the latest client version. That seems to be working fine. The problem is in the next part.

```
class FetchChampion: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var clientVersion = FetchVersion()
    @Published var datas = [String()] {
        didSet {
            print("\(self.datas.count) champions logged in ChampionData")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        print(clientVersion.version) // Prints nothing
        var ver : String = "10.15.1"
        var urlString : String {
                return "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/\(ver)/data/en_US/champion.json"
        }
//        var urlString : String {
//                return "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/\(self.clientVersion.version)/data/en_US/champion.json"
//        }
        print(urlString)
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(dataGappu, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = dataGappu {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ChampionData.self, from: jsonData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let sortedData = decodedData.data.keys.sorted()
                        self.datas = sortedData
                        //print(self.version)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

When I try to use the published var from FetchVersion I am unable to use it during the string interpolation when creating urlString, and it prints out the "Error". The init() works fine when I manually define the patch version (i.e., "10.15.1").

I know Swift has 2 phase initialization, but I just don't seem to be able to understand if that is why the code won't work as I need or if I am missing something else.

All criticism and tips would be constructive since I am very new to the language and iOS as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing an asynchronous call in the init of FetchVersion so the data has not been returned yet when you try to access it in the other class. Overall I think it is a bad idea to download data like this in an init method so my suggest is to re-design your solution to avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 0):

As @Joakim Danielson mentioned, you're trying to access the data before the request comes through. You're essentially retrieving the init-value of `FetchVersion.version`, which in you case is `String()`.

If you would like to print the value when it comes through, you could do this with combine as you use `@ObservableObject`. This subscriber can be created in the init function of `FetchChampion`. Make sure, however, to store the subscriber in a cancellable.

You can read more about this in the Combine docs. [Here's a link to a great tutorial on Combine by Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7864801-combine-getting-started).

```swift
clientVersion.$version.sink { value in
  print(value)
}.store(in: &cancellables)
```